# Mirth 3.2 - Retrieve SENT message from Web Service Sender

Tags: mirth

I'm using a Web Service Sender destination in my Mirth 3.2. I'd like to retrieve (in response editing, postprocessor, etc.) the message it sent, namely the SOAP request built by the destination connector, namely the message I see in the "Dashboard - Channel Messages" selecting the radio button "Sent" in the "messages" tab.

Is it possible?

Comment: Just surfing across and found this post. I am facing a similar issue now. Is it something you guys found the solution for?